# How to get App ID(App name) for which my APN's certificate is expired?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I received a mail from Apple when my one of the certificate is revoked.

Mail says

**Your APNs Production iOS certificate has been revoked.**

**Certificate**: APNs Production iOS

**Team Name**: "My team name".

**Any provisioning profiles that include this certificate are no longer valid and must be regenerated for future use.**

But my question is how can i know for which application my push notification certificate is expired ?

Is there any way by i can find application name on developer account ?

Comment: You should be able to see it in Certificates in your Keychain Access on your mac.

Comment: Yes that is i am doing. but it won't work in each case as if certificate is not installed in my keychain , or i change my pc and it has new keychain.

Comment: I think you should ask this in Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Thanks @CandostDagdeviren, i am doing the same but Stackoverflow is also a good medium where people are interacting and i am expecting answer from here.